# ISJSON in Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL pool

Tags: json, t-sql, azure-synapse

I am having an issue with the ISJSON function in Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL pool.

The code snippets below executes correctly in SQL Server 2016+

```
--test1
SELECT myJsonField
FROM myTable
WHERE ISJSON(myJsonField) = 1

--test2
SELECT ISJSON('{"a":1}')
```

but when I execute the same code on an Azure Synapse SQL Pool I get the following error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

According to the documentation, this function should be available in Synapse: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest

Azure Synapse version:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
--Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.15661.0 Jun 20 2022 23:32:43 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
```

Note: OPENJSON still works fine

EDIT:
Screenshot from SSMS:
[image]

Screenshot from Synapse Workspace:
[image]

EDIT: I have updated the title and question to clarify that this is a DEDICATED SQL Pool.

Comment: *"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."* There is no `AS` in that batch.

Comment: I know. That's part of what makes it so confusing...

Comment: Update: I can confirm that this was simply a bug introduced by Azure that has been resolved in Version 10.0.15665.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with some sample values in my local environment, and it is working without errors.

```
select @@version version_name

--ex:1
 declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{"time":"2015-04-29T07:12:20.9100000Z","callingimsi":"466920403025604","switch1":"China","switch2":"Germany"}'
 select @json as json_value
 where ISJSON(@json)=1

 --ex:2
 declare @json1 nvarchar(max) = 'abc'
 select @json1 as json_value1
 where ISJSON(@json1)=1

 --ex:3
 SELECT ISJSON('{"a":1}') as validate_json
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not getting the same result as you, I have added a screenshot to my original post.

Comment: Hi, what version of SSMS you are using and have you tried running the code in the Azure synapse workspace?

Comment: SSMS Version is v18.12.1.

I also have the same error using the Synapse Workspace, I have added a screenshot to the original post.

I also have the same error when this code snippet is run as part of a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

We've hit this same issue.
ISJSON function works normally on Azure SQL databases, works normally on serverles SQL pool in Synapse, but fails in dedicated SQL pool in Synapse. Looks like MS updated the ISJSON function in Azure, but not all Azure SQL databases have the same version deployed.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share some way to confirm this or point to some documentation showing the change to the function. As it currently stands this doesn't help resolve the issue.